# Common resistor for pulling up unused pins of ATmega2560

Tags: pcb, avr, pullup

I am designing a PCB with ATmega2560 MCU. I have 50 unused pins in my design. I was wondering if I can pull up these 50 pins using 5 resistors such that 10 pins have a common pull up resistor. Is that recommended?

Comment: You could also just enable the internal pull-up resistors in the MCU.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can... but i wouldn't. And it's probably not recommended (in a way of there is no advantage of doing it. Just more solderwork.).

The Aruino Mega, and most of the other Arduinos, have internal Pullups (20k).

To activate these pullups you have to use following code:

```
pinMode(pin, INPUT);           // set pin to input
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);       // turn on pullup resistors
```

You can also use port manipulation for that matter:

```
DDRA = 0x00;      //Direction of PORT A is set to INPUT
PORTA = 0xFF;     //Turn on 20k pullup resistor
```

But i never had any problems with leaving the unused Pins floating.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are "unused" then yes, this can be done. However care should be taken that pins of different designs are not used. In theory you might want a slightly lower resistance value to make the pullup "stronger."

If the pins are high impedance/inputs then this shouldn't ever truly become a problem. There is leakage current and so this might be something to consider since all of the pins will be pulling from that resistor's node. It might also not mean anything for you, which is fine too, design permitting.

Just remember that the pins are tied together and that if one ever becomes an output and pulls the line down, all the pins are affected in some way.

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you to do with them?